# Failure of the code calling the function “rasterize” in R: NAs or no slots

Tags: r, rasterization

I have some problems to convert a shapefile into a raster. I used the function `rasterize` (package `raster`) but all raster values are equal to NA.

Following the answers to this question [rasterize produces a raster full of NA values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133619/rasterize-produces-a-raster-full-of-na-values). The raster aligns with the SpatialPolygons:

```
r.ext <- raster(shp.prj, res=30)
rfn <- rasterize(shp.prj, r.ext, field="land_cover_type")

class(shp.prj$land_cover_type)
# [1] "character"
```

But I have always NAs in the output raster (`rfn`).

```
> rfn
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : -74, -44, 15.875, 45.875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)
```

Here are some information on the input shapefile (`shp.prj`) and the input raster (`r.ext`):

```
> shp.prj
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 78152 
extent      : -74, -71.5, 45, 45.875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3

> r.ext
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : -74, -44, 15.875, 45.875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

I also tried to reduce the raster resolution (`res(r.ext) <- 0.05`) but I obtained this error message:

```
> rfn <- rasterize(shp.prj, r.ext, field="land_cover_type")
Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])) : 
  trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Following the answers to this question [r raster package rasterize failing:no slots](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64343/r-raster-package-rasterize-failingno-slots), I also tested:

```
rfn <- rasterize(shp.prj, r.ext, shp.prj$land_cover_type)
```

but I have always the error message:

```
Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])) : 
  trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Comment: r.ext does not have the the same extent as r.ext <- raster(extent(shp.prj)) - so that presumably is not the actual code involved here. (You could just do raster(shp.prj) to avoid the need for projection()<-). Otherwise I would try rasterize(shp.prj, r.ext, field=shp.prj$land_cover_type)

Comment: Thank you very much midsummer. I have NAs in both the input raster `r.ext` and the output raster `rfn` (I added the `rfn` output in the post). I also tried to do `r.ext <- raster(shp.prj)` to avoid `projection()` and `rasterize(shp.prj, r.ext, field=shp.prj$land_cover_type)` but I have always NAs in the output raster `rfn` with the raster resolution = 30. With the raster resolution = 0.05, I have always the error message `with "no slots"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data is in a geographic projection, you cannot assign 30 to the resolution. If you look at the result of doing so, the r.ext raster has 1 row, 1 column and 1 value. So, that problem solved.

Try defining the resolution in the call to raster. Since sometimes nodata begets nodata, I am assigning a value of 1 to all cells in the reference raster "r.ext". You will see that the resulting raster now has 18 rows, 50 columns and 900 values.

```
library(raster)
r.ext <- raster(extent(-74, -71.5, 45, 45.875), resolution = 0.05)
  r.ext[] <- rep(1,ncell(r.ext))
  projection(r.ext) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")

r.ext  
plot(r.ext)
```

Now (this will make @mdsumner's head explode) try a direct call to the @data slot to access the "land_cover_type" column. I have found this necessary in the past. These packages are ever evolving and what was previously necessary may not be in the next release. However, I have never had success simply passing the column name to the argument (ie., field="land_cover_type"), it always has to be a call the the object with the name (eg., x$land_cover_type or x@data$land_cover_type). I have found that sometimes coercing to a SpatialPolygons object sidesteps issues.

```
rfn <- rasterize(as(shp.prj, "SpatialPolygons"), r.ext, shp.prj@data[,"land_cover_type"], fun="first")
```

Following the example from the functions help, here is a worked example.

```
library(raster)
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- list(p1, hole)
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0))
pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3)
pols <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(pols, data.frame(ID=1:3))
ref <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=45)

r <- rasterize(pols, ref, field = pols@data[,"ID"], fun="first")
plot(r)
```

I would highly recommend selecting a distance based projection, reprojecting your polygon data and then running this analysis. Then you can define a cell size of 30m.

This is not a failure of the rasterize function but rather a failing of the analysis/code calling the function. Developers work very hard, and for free, to provide these packages. Please do not intimate a bug or failure until your are sure that the fault is not yours.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeffrey for your answer. I re-projected my polygon data by using a projected coordinate system as follows: `shp.prj <- spTransform(shp,CRS("+proj=...."))`. Then, I re-built my input raster as follows:  `r.ext <- raster(extent(sief.prj), resolution = 30)`. Indeed, my raster has now several rows, columns and values. However, I still have a problem with `rasterize` even if I do `shp.prj@data[,"land_cover_type"]`. I obtain `Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])): trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots` .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the expected input to the rasterize function is a SpatialPolygons object. Try my modification to the rasterize syntax and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeffrey for your help. It works when the field "Land_cover_type" is a factor. When the field is a character, I still have the error message: `Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])): trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots`.

Comment: Since a raster has to be numeric I imagine that this is because it has to coerce the column to numeric before conversion. The underlying code is probably assuming a factor when the column is non-numeric. This is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Please show your `sessionInfo()` and `traceback()` after the error occurs. This error message: `Error in cbind(poly, rbind(poly[-1, ], poly[1, ])): trying to get slot "coords" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots` is very odd as it would normally only occur when expecting `SpatialPoints`.

As it seems you have very many, presumably very small, polygons, Consider using `rasterize(..., small=TRUE)`.

Here to illustrate how it should work:

```
#example data
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- list(p1, hole)
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0))
p <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3)
p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, data.frame(id = 5:7, 
                            landcover=c('forest','savanna','forest')))

# now rasterize

r <- raster(p, res=2.5)
r <- rasterize(p, r, field='landcover')
```